# How do you append images that are already created with appendImage?

Tags: php, imagick

The php website lists the following [example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-appendimages.php):

```
 <?php

/* Create new imagick object */
$im = new Imagick();

/* create red, green and blue images */
$im->newImage(100, 50, "red");
$im->newImage(100, 50, "green");
$im->newImage(100, 50, "blue");

/* Append the images into one */
$im->resetIterator();
$combined = $im->appendImages(true);

/* Output the image */
$combined->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $combined;
?>
```

How do I use an image generated from a URL instead, such as

```
$image = new Imagick("sampleImage.jpg");
```

so that I could append the loaded images instead of using `newImage()`

Answer (score 6):

Use `Imagick::addImage` to "combine" the various Imagicks into one and use `appendImages` afterwards, for example (addapted from [here](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-addimage.php#refsect1-function.imagick-addimage-errors)):

```
<?php
$filelist = array("fileitem1.png","fileitem2.png","fileitem3.png");

$all = new Imagick();

foreach($filelist as $file){
    $im = new Imagick($file);       
    $all->addImage($im);
}
/* Append the images into one */
$all->resetIterator();
$combined = $all->appendImages(true);

/* Output the image */
$combined->setImageFormat("png");
header("Content-Type: image/png");
echo $combined;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Handle returned by fopen() to use image from url.

example :

```
<?php
/* Read images from URL */
$handle1 = fopen('http://yoursite.com/your-image1.jpg', 'rb');
$handle2 = fopen('http://yoursite.com/your-image2.jpg', 'rb');

/* Create new imagick object */
$img = new Imagick();

/* Add to Imagick object */
$img->readImageFile($handle1);
$img->readImageFile($handle2);

/* Append the images into one */
$img->resetIterator();
$combined = $img->appendImages(true);

/* path to save you image */
$path = "/images/combined-image.jpg";

/* Output the image */
$combined->setImageFormat("jpg");
$combined->writeimage( $path );

/* destroy imagick objects */
$img->destroy();
$combined->destroy();

?>
```