# Resize issue : Dynamic Image creation on the base of user Input : Imagick : PHP : Resize Auto

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am creating a dynamic Image on the base of User Input where I have 2 textboxes and 1 Image upload in form,

```
<?php
/* Create some objects */
$customImage = new Imagick('test.png');//dynamic image
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( '#FFF' );

/* New image */
$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

/* Black text */
$draw->setFillColor('#a28430');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Roboto-Black.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );


/* Create text */
$image->compositeImage($customImage,Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 10, 20);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 50, 0, "First Line");// dynaimc text
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 70, 0, "second line");// dynamic text


/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;
```

Current Image output of is

[image]

My sample uploaded Image

[image]

I already have pre-define font so I am using at as `Roboto-Black.ttf` and font-size , here I am `$customImage` getting as dynamic Image(where user uploaded) the Image and `First Line` and `Second Line` I am getting dynamic as well as `test.png` is also dynamic ,

So, when I create the Image with I am defining the Image size `$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);` sometimes Image size is too big when `test.png` is small so after creating an Image is there any way to create the result Image as "auto" resize so it will auto adjust with the dynamic font and dynamic Image?

There is `[resizeImage][3]` from the but as a parameter it is expecting the height and width and I want as "auto"

Comment: I do not understand your question. Are you trying to resize the Lorem Ipsum image or the text image?  Why not resize the text image to fit the Lorem Ipsum?  Either way, get the dimensions of the two images and resize accordingly one way or the other according to the width of each image.

Comment: No, I have 2 textboxes, 1 file upload on HTML form, where user can write whatever they want, and upload the Image what they want, so on form submit I need to create new Image with 2 text line(from 2 textboxes) and 1 Image which user uploaded and save in server,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to dynamically size things, it is probably easier to just pick a fixed to work with and scale what the user provides to match that.

For the upload it would look something like this:

```php
define('IDEAL_WIDTH', 800);
define('IDEAL_HEIGHT', 800);

$customImage = new Imagick('test.png');//dynamic image
$customImage->scaleImage(IDEAL_WIDTH, IDEAL_HEIGHT);
```

And for your image where you are drawing text it would be:

```php
$image->newImage(IDEAL_WIDTH, IDEAL_HEIGHT, $pixel);
```

You'll need to adjust where you are drawing your text slightly, but that should be really easy because you are working in a fixed area.

Other versions of this are to get a little crazier and ask the user for certain things like *where* they want the text and what font sizes to use.

Answer (score 1):

Here's code that will perform a resize of the image based on the geometry (width) of the widest of two annotation text lines. This should help solve part of the challenges you have.

The code:

```
<?php

// >> Q: Resize image to the width of a text box (2 lines) using Imagick in PHP
// >> URL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62772906/resize-issue-dynamic-image-creation-on-the-base-of-user-input-imagick-php
//
// >> How to get geometry of an image using Imagick in PHP
// >> > https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.getimagegeometry.php
//
// >> How to get dimensions of text using Imagick in PHP
// >> > https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.queryfontmetrics.php

/* Create some objects */
$customImage = new Imagick('test.png');//dynamic image
$ciGeo=$customImage->getImageGeometry();  // >> 
$ciWidth=$ciGeo['width'];                 // >>
$ciHeight=$ciGeo['height'];               // >>
$ciAspect=$ciWidth/$ciHeight;             // >> > Aspect ratio (eg. 1=square)
$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( '#FFF' );

/* Black text */
$draw->setFillColor('#a28430');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Roboto-Black.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

// >> Get two annotation text lines
$textLine1 = "First Line";
$textLine2 = "second line";
    
// >> Get text lines metrics to calculate geometry text box
$metricsL1 = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $textLine1);
$metricsL2 = $image->queryFontMetrics($draw, $textLine2);
$textWidth = $metricsL1['textWidth'];
if ($metricsL2['textWidth'] > $metricsL1['textWidth'])
{ $textWidth = $metricsL2['textWidth'];
};

// >> Resize images based on text box width
$diWidth = $textWidth + 20;                     // >> +20 = 2*10 padding
$diHeight = ($textWidth + 20)*$ciAspect;        // >> Height = width * aspect ratio 
$customImage->scaleImage($diWidth, $diHeight);  // >> Scale

// New image
$image->newImage($diWidth, $diHeight, $pixel);  // ++ 

// Create text
$image->compositeImage($customImage,Imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0);
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 50, 0, $textLine1);// dynaimc text >>
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 70, 0, $textLine2);// dynamic text >>

// Give image a format
$image->setImageFormat('png');

// Output the image with headers
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $image;

?>
```

[a sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU1Cl.jpg)
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0SK3.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a "hint" than answer! I do not use Imagick as I prefer Imagemagick with exec();

There is an example at the bottom of this thread: [How do you append images that are already created with appendImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280813/how-do-you-append-images-that-are-already-created-with-appendimag)

I was thinking along the lines of this before I found the above and you may be able to combine the two:

```
/* Create some objects */

$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$pixel = new ImagickPixel( '#FFF' );

/* New image */
$image->newImage(800, 75, $pixel);

/* Black text */
$draw->setFillColor('white');

/* Font properties */
$draw->setFont('Roboto-Black.ttf');
$draw->setFontSize( 30 );

/* Create text */
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 50, 0, "First Line");// dynaimc text
$image->annotateImage($draw, 10, 70, 0, "second line");// dynamic text

// Get the size of the image to esize the text
$size = getimagesize('MB75H.jpg');

// Resize the text - need to calculate the height from the new width
$image->resizeimage($size[0],100,Imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS,1);

// Load the second image
$image = new Imagick('MB75H.jpg');//dynamic image
$image->resetIterator();
$combined = $image->appendImages(true);

/* Give image a format */
$image->setImageFormat('png');

/* Output the image with headers */
header('Content-type: image/png');
echo $combined;
```